# Automatically Batch File if still running after 5 minutes i.e. hanging

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a BAT File which connects to an FTP site to send/receive files.  On rare occasions the batch file will hang if there is an issue with the network.  I would like to know if there is a command to automatically exit the batch file if it has been running longer than 5 minutes?  This would be placed in the batch file I assume, a kind of countdown from when it first opens.

Thanks.
Brett

Answer (score 0):

You have to have two windows.

```
start ftp etc
Timeout /t 300
taskkill /im ftp.exe /f
```

This will kill all ftp.exe not just one. **NOTE** this relys on the fact we are running ftp without running cmd in the second console window.